Post-process Bindgen generated bindings to add extra types
I am using Bindgen to generate binding for a somewhat "inconvenient" C library. Currently it is generating a whole lot of types for function pointers of the form:
pub type lib_func_XXX = ::core::option::Option<
    unsafe extern "C" fn(
        ....
    ) -> ReturnType,
>;

I am interested in having a union type encapsulating all these types such as:
union LibFn {
   XXX: lib_func_XXX,
   YYY: lib_func_YYY,
   .....
}

Is there any way of generating such a union from the types generated by Bindgen, given the types are following specific naming pattern? All this of course at the build stage in build.rs script.

Assuming this is following up from the answer to your last question. I don't think a union is sustainable; bindgen won't make it for you. You could do it on your own outside of bindgen, but that's starting to feel like a bad idea. Are you really expecting a lot of function transmutation?

@kmdreko Yeah, it is related to the same project. I think it is indeed not doable using bindgen. But looks like I might be able to postprocess it using the syn crate.. if I manage to do it will post an answer here.

This may not be helpful, but is there some reason that you need a huge union of types which are all the same size and layout? You can make your life easier by just writing a helper function which you call like convert<lib_func_XXX>(x) instead of writing x.XXX. I guess the union version has the advantage of being slightly less characters to type, but offers you no additional safety.

@user2407038 That's the option I am using right now (as in transmute the specific pointer), but there is more to it. The issue is that the actual pointer value is to be searched using some ID value with a name formatted as something with XXX in it. So currently I have a very ugly macro involving the paste crate to both compose the ID, the function type and do the transmutation. With the union approach I am hoping to make it cleaner. Not sure it will be, but I'll try and see what looks better.

What do you mean by search? If you mean that you have something like HashMap<String, LibFn> then you could just define type LibFn = Option<unsafe extern "C" fn() ->()> as the union offers no extra properties. If you already have a macro doing some sort of string or identifier based mapping to type names, you can just modify that same macro to generate the union type. It seems like that macro could be important context to this quesiton

@user2407038 There are a bunch of tables installed by the library in the memory which, after a specific table walk give the function pointer based on integer ID. So from bindgen I basically get something like a bunch of IDs const func_id_XXX: u32 = .... and function types as described in the question. Then I have a function fn get_function_pointer(id: u32) -> Option<unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ReturnType>. And this is what I have to work with.
